# Where would additional IP addresses assigned to a NIC be configured on CentOS 4.4?

Tags: networking, centos

I have a very old CentOS 4.4 machine with multiple IP addresses assigned to `eth0`. However these ip addresses are not configured in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` where I would expect them to be i.e.

```
ifcfg-eth0:0
ifcfg-eth0:1
ifcfg-eth0:2
```

...and so on.

`ifconfig` shows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:4B:09:FE:39
          inet addr:#.#.#.98  Bcast:#.#.#.127  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:4bff:fe09:fe39/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:361746101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3276279311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2539629048 (2.3 GiB)  TX bytes:2436041815 (2.2 GiB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:4B:09:FE:39
          inet addr:#.#.#.99  Bcast:#.#.#.127  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:4B:09:FE:39
          inet addr:#.#.#.104  Bcast:#.#.#.127  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth0:3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:4B:09:FE:39
          inet addr:#.#.#.105  Bcast:#.#.#.127  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

(I've replaced the first three octets with `#` to protect the innocent)

But I'm at a loss as to where these are being configured.

I've also checked:

```
/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices
/etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default
/etc/sysconfig/network
```

I've also done a `find / -name eth0*` but to no avail.

What other locations would these additional addresses be configured?

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` wouldn't be unexpected and otherwise use `grep -r <ip-address>` on the files in /etc/

Comment: @HBruijn - just as you commented, I found them in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found these hiding inside:

`/etc/rc.local`

Where's there's a bunch of `ifconfig` commands configuring these extra addresses.

Comment: As an aside, CentOS 4 stopped getting security updates back in 2012, so this machine needs to be updated, and certainly can not be on the open Internet.

Comment: @samiam - yes, that is well understood.